# What caterpillar is this?

Tags: identification, pest-control, pest-damage, caterpillar

And how do I get rid of it...
The beasts are about 2 cm long.
At first I thought there was a parasite in my plants since I only saw the poppy-seed-like excrement. Until someone mentioned it was caterpillar poop. I have been trying different methods.... including tobacco water, Pressured water and lately three applications of Take Down, spaced two weeks apart (at night to avoid collateral damage).
Still the pests are eating away!

Most of the moths I see are extremely small (1cm wingspan) and brownish. I've also seen some white (cabbage moths) but they seem to be visiting? I have no idea what plant this is BTW.... As it has not flowered from all the damage.[image: mysterious green caterpillar][image]

Comment: Have you watched the caterpillars moving along a stem - do they loop themselves up in the middle rather than just walking along?

Comment: They inch along. I have not seen them doing the inverted U thing...

Comment: By the number of legs it looks like a cabbage looper, also known as inch worm - turns into a small grey moth (wingspan 1 to 1.5 inches) with a silvery V shaped spot on each wing... but it should loop itself up as it moves

Comment: The reason your plant isn't flowering is NOT because of this little guy or any insect.  We need to know what you are using for fertilizer, too much nitrogen for example will promote vegetative growth not reproductive growth or flowers and fruit.  Lots of Fracas or insect poop on this leaf.  Picture of entire plant, what you are using for soil, is this in the garden, did you use garden soil in the pot if this is in a pot?

Comment: Plant had curly very tiny new growth that was being eaten by the caterpillars.  I started 2 months ago fertilizing with Dr. Earth. Premium gold all purpose fertilizer. Now plant looks very bushy. It is in the garden. It was here when I moved in. Sorry, not enough rep to post more pictures or link. It looks healthy and recovering, but far too many caterpillars.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_MvH5zQTSVhQlVUM1RnOE8tOEE/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Its a shrub, possibly  deciduous, but not sure what it is - its obviously been cut back quite hard at some point, judging by the thickness of the woody stems. Do you know if it loses its leaves in winter?

Comment: Winter is mild here... We barely get below 50 F. I am in zone 6.

Comment: It doesn't loose its leaves.